# How to combine Where clauses in xQuery

Tags: xquery

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I'm trying to set two conditions through using "where" and they each work alone, but when I combine them I get a dump of every file.

If I simply have:

```
for $i in collection("/db/people")
where $i//lastname="Smith"
return $i
```

I get two listings because there are two types (a & b).

If I have

```
for $i in collection("/db/people")
where $i//type="a"
return $i
```

I get 538 listings which is everything of type "a".

However, if I have:

```
for $i in collection("/db/people")
where  $i//type="a" and $i//lastname="Smith"
return $i
```

I get all of the files. Why isn't it just giving me the single file with the name and type I've specified? It seems like I'm missing something obvious!

Comment: It could be that the parser you are using isn't respecting operator precedence properly. Did you try wrapping the left and right hand operands of the 'and' operator in parenthesis like this yet: `($i//type="a") and ($i//lastname="Smith")`?

Answer (score 5):

You can try your solution on http://try.zorba-xquery.com/, it works fine.
For instance:

```
let $people := (<people><type>a</type><lastname>Smith</lastname></people>, <people><type>a</type><lastname>Foobar</lastname></people>)
for $i in $people
where  $i//type="a" and $i//lastname="Smith"
return $i
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks correct to me (I've tried it with BaseX). It might be that your XQuery Processor does something wrong; which XML/XQuery engine are you using?

Answer (score -1):

eXist-db is much more efficient when using predicate filters in stead of the 'where' clause. Please could you try that?